# Elasticsearch replication cluster with different OS

Tags: elasticsearch

[image]

If I am running one ES on Windows server, another ES on Linux, and the third ES on Unix, can I cluster them and make them replicate each other? **Is it possible?**

```
Server A      Windows     192.168.0.100
Server B      Linux       192.168.0.101
Server C      Unix        192.168.0.102
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it possible as soon as they can "see" each other in network.

I think more important that should have similar configuration in terms of memory and CPU this would be more important but again it depends on performance you are looking for.